# Does Gatheral formula for local volatility translate to a constraint on implied volatility

Tags: implied-volatility, local-volatility

In Gatheral's "The Volatility Surface : A Practitioner's Guide", Equation (1.10) page 13, the following relation linking squared local volatility and squared implied volatility is expressed :

$$\begin{equation}
\sigma^2(y, t) = \frac{\partial_T w}{1 - \frac{y}{w} \partial_y w + \frac{1}{4}(-\frac{1}{4} - \frac{1}{w} + \frac{y^2}{w^2})(\partial_y w)^2 + \frac{1}{2} \partial_{y,y}w}\end{equation}$$
where $w(y, t) = \sigma_{BS}^2(y, t)t$ and $y = \log K/F$.

This seem to mean that
$1 - \frac{y}{w} \partial_y w + \frac{1}{4}(-\frac{1}{4} - \frac{1}{w} + \frac{y^2}{w^2})(\partial_y w)^2 + \frac{1}{2} \partial_{y,y}w > 0$.

Does this inequality have a known interpretation, and a name ?

Answer (score 5):

This is actually explained in the article "[Arbitrage-free SVI volatility surfaces](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1204.0646.pdf)" by Gatheral :
It means that the surface is free of butterfly arbitrage.